# Getting attributes from a lyr file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I have downloaded a crime dataset from imaps, an online GIS server for Raleigh, NC.  The dataset shows the location and types of crimes in the past 90 days.  Using the info tool, I can see all of the attributes of an individual crime point, such as the date, category of crime, and address.  I cannot get an attribute table or use a selection query for this layer (it downloads as an .lyr file), which is what I would like to do to filter the data.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Lyr file is a just reference file which has to go to the data source to read the data and show the attributes. You might still be going to the GIS Server when clicking the features in the map. Have you also downloaded the data along with the .lyr file? Maybe a shapefile or a geodatabase archived?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible from this server to download the data--lyr is the only option--no shapefile or gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lyr files aren't data, they're just symbology, and that one in particular uses a service rather than local data. It was helpful to search out the data behind the service for the asker.

Did some google searching for you:

I am assuming you used this online tool

http://www.raleighnc.gov/home/content/Police/Articles/OnlineCrimeMapping.html

This is the service that outputs crime for the last 90 days

http://maps.raleighnc.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/Crime/Crime/MapServer

The Data can be found and downloaded here on their open data site:

https://data.raleighnc.gov/category/public-safety

https://data.raleighnc.gov/Police/Daily-Police-Incidents/guyh-emm5

Comment: Thank you--this is exactly the site I accessed and I've found the data where you suggested!

Comment: You might edit your answer to include more explanation along the lines of Alex's comment - that lyr files aren't data, they're just symbology, and that one in particular uses a service rather than local data. It was helpful to search out the data behind the service for the asker.